# TTR: Destination ticket value changes in the America 1910 expansion

Tags: ticket-to-ride

The BGG summary for the expansion mentions this:

> a complete replacement deck of the 141 cards from the original game deck: 30 Destination Tickets (4 cards have a reduced value from Ticket to Ride)

What were these reductions and why were they necessary?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Which tickets were changed?

The following destination tickets received a decrease in value:  <sup>(Source: [this post](http://www.daysofwonder.com/en/msg/?goto=67600#msg_num_0) by [Days of Wonder Forums](http://www.daysofwonder.com/en/forums/) user "[Baron Von Schmidt original](http://www.daysofwonder.com/en/usrinfo/?id=245866)")</sup>

1. **Sault St. Marie to Oklahoma City**: now **8** points
2. **Los Angeles to Miami**: now **19** points
3. **Los Angeles to New York**: now **20** points
4. **Seattle to New York**: now **20** points

### Tickets Probably Over-valued

It appears that the minimum number of trains required to complete a destination ticket was the *starting point* for assigning each ticket a point value. The claim is made  <sup>(in [this post](http://www.daysofwonder.com/en/msg/?goto=179787#msg_num_3) by [Days of Wonder Forums](http://www.daysofwonder.com/en/forums/) user "[Caboose](http://www.daysofwonder.com/en/usrinfo/?id=13984)")</sup>  that Alan Moon (the game's designer) said the ticket values were not supposed to be the shortest route between two cities. Lacking the context that this may have been said in, I believe the intent was to put to rest worries that some ticket values were mistakes or misprints, rather than to deny all connection between tickets' values and their minimum lengths.  <sup>([This post](http://www.daysofwonder.com/en/msg/?goto=17836#msg_num_1) by Caboose from several years earlier shows (s)he had previously believed the issue was due to a misprint.)</sup>

Additionally, if the changes were to "fix" the tickets to match their minimum lengths, they didn't fix all of them. It's been pointed out  <sup>(in [this post](http://www.daysofwonder.com/en/usrinfo/?id=420492) by [Days of Wonder Forums](http://www.daysofwonder.com/en/forums/) user "[DiscJet](http://www.daysofwonder.com/en/usrinfo/?id=6686)")</sup>  that the **Los Angeles to Chicago** ticket and the 1910 expansion's **Las Vegas to Miami** ticket are each worth more than their shortest length.

I conclude that Mr. Moon decided the four changed routes were somewhat over-valued, at least for the *1910* rules (if not in general).

<sub>**Attribution Note:** I got the idea to look through the Days of Wonder Forums from [aramis' answer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/3348/ttr-destination-ticket-value-changes-in-the-america-1910-expansion/3355#3355). I don't have access to my copy of Ticket to Ride and the 1910 expansion at the moment, so I can't verify the route lengths or values myself.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Point values were probably corrections as they probably intended the point values to be based on the shortest path.

For example the Seattle - New York ticket was 22 in the original game and is now 20 is the America 1910 expansion.  You can get from Seattle to New York with 20 trains.

Answer (score 0):

Days of Wonder stated in their forums that the 1910 changes were to reflect the shortest route valuations. (I can't find the post right now.)

Likewise, all other tickets adhere to that basic rule.